# VLOOKUP alternative using three lookup values

Tags: excel, vlookup

As you know Excel only lets you use one lookup value, but I need to compare three lookup values to find a fourth value.

For example in the screenshot below I want to use the information `name`, `pet` and `business` to find who the `teacher` is on the second sheet.  For the record this is just example data to understand how to perform the task and I need to apply this to over 600 rows!

First sheet:
[Here is the first sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jNBl.png)

Second sheet:
[Here is my second sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56Pmf.png)

Edit: I keep getting an error when I try to enter this formula: =index(Sheet2!A2:G7,MATCH(Sheet1!A5&Sheet!C5&Sheet1!D5,Sheet2!B2:B7&Sheet2!D2:D7&Sheet2!E2:E7,0))

Comment: It's fine to filter for this spreadsheet but I need to apply the same logic on a spreadsheet with a lot more rows which would take up a considerable amount of time and I may need to do this again many more times in the future

Comment: Thank you, do you have any suggestion as to how I can do this for this example?

Comment: Is there no formula I can use in this situation such as index and match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Vlookup()`, you can use Index/Match, which is a nice alternative that lets you do this.

The formula correctly returns "Miss Smith":
[image]
Note: This is entered as an array formula with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>

So, the basic layout of the formula is:
`=Index([range to return],match([single look up value],[range where that value would be],0))`

You can combine lookup values by concatenating them, as you can see in the screenshot.  So, the single lookup values are `A2`, `C2`, and `D2`.  And, you'd expect to find "Sarah" in the range `G2:G3`, "Dog" in `H2:H3`, etc.

Please let me know if I can clarify anything.

Edit: To help visualize the two sheets thing.  I put the table (which you will lookup *from*) on a sheet called "Data Sheet".  The table we need to complete is on "Main WS".

Here's "Main WS":
[image]

and the "Data Sheet":

[image]

Comment: How would you do this using a seperate tab as I seem to be getting errors to do with the sheet name?

Comment: @table - When setting up the formula, instead of typing the range names in, actually select them via the cursor.  The format would be like `=Index('Sheet Name'!A2:A10, ...`

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but for some reason it still showed an error

Comment: @table - Can you post the formula you are working with? Index/Match will work for sure, so it's just some convention with your workbook.  (Perhaps also post the worksheet names).  What error is it returning?

Comment: Edit: I keep getting an error when I try to enter this formula: =index(Sheet2!A2:G7,MATCH(Sheet1!A5&Sheet!C5&Sheet1!D5,Sheet2!B2:B7&Sheet2!D2:D7&Sheet2!E2:E7,0))

Comment: What error is it? `#VALUE`, `#N/A`, `#NAME`, etc.?  Also, are you entering this with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER? (Don't just hit `Enter`, press the three keys at the same time).  Finally, if your formula is on your `Sheet1`, you can remove the reference to that sheet in the first part of the `Match()`.

Comment: its #N/A when I press ctrl+shift+enter and the formula is on sheet one but I need to find the values from sheet 1 on sheet 2

Comment: @table - I have updated my post with screenshots. Does this help to clarify?

Comment: @table - Why are you trying to get the entire row across Sheet2!A2:G7?

Comment: @table - Use this (thanks for pointing that out @Jeeped), `=index(Sheet2!G2:G7,MATCH(A5&C5&D5,Sheet2!B2:B7&Sheet2!D2:D7‌​&Sheet2!E2:E7,0)) `   ...(I'm assuming your Teacher Names are in G2:G7).

Comment: btw Bruce, not to start picking nits but have you noticed a sharp rise in the use of screenshots to show sample data and expected results? I've been 'quietly' protesting by only offering a screenshot of the solution formula (thereby forcing the OP to retype it out themselves) but I find the trend disconcerting to say the least.

Comment: @Jeeped - Yeah, I have noticed that too - and I agree, I'm not a big fan either.  Haha, I like your protest though, not a bad idea.  I may just start asking that they copy/paste data instead of screenshots before I can help :P  I've started using screenshots more in my answers, but hopefully they're making things more clear (I don't want to include them just for their own sake!).

Comment: As far as screenshots in the answer goes, I find that a picture is worth a thousand words. I get only a small percentage of 'it doesn't work' replies when I add a screenshot and I think this has a lot to do with the OP seeing that it works and trying harder before claiming it doesn't. Besides, it isn't like I'm asking them to retype anything (unless they have only provided screenshots themselves!). If this trend for the OP's screenshots continues, I may try to get together a chatroom session where some of the regulars can discuss ways to discourage it.

Comment: @Jeeped - good point in that a screenshot in the answer may get them to try a little harder.  I mainly use them to prove that what I'm talking about does work (usually) and I'm not just throwing out random ideas (usually).

Answer (score 0):

Given the cyclic calulation and disregard for the [Worksheet.UsedRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx) that the [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) exhibits, you will want to cut down the ranges for the lookups to the minimmum required. Pick a column that will typically determine the extent of the lookup range and use that to define the end point of each lookup column.

Sheet2:

[image]

Sheet1:

[image]

The formula in Sheet1!E2 is,

[image]

Fill down as necessary.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused by the formula, please could you explain it?

Comment: Hmmm... what part of it?

Comment: why is there zzz in the match bit and what does the 15,6 bit represent on the first line?

Comment: Put `=match("zzz", g:g)` in any cell (not column g) in Sheet2. It returns the row number of the last populated cell in column g. Then type a few abc's below the last populated cell in column g. The formula's result changes. So this is used to determine exactly how many entries there are in the column that returns the value and that same row number is used to define all of the other columns so that they each use exactly enough rows as is absolutely necessary. The `15, 6` can be explained by clicking on the documentation link I provided for the AGGREGATE function.