# VLOOKUP - Double column comparison

Tags: excel

I have two spreadsheets in a document: [Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VctlC.jpg) and
[CompleteResults](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyJab.jpg)

I need to look for `SecondName` and `SecondID` in the `CompleteResults` sheet, and paste them to the matching `Name-ID` rows in the `Results` sheet, that are now blank.

The `Name-ID` rows that are not found at `CompleteResults` can be edited with a "not found" flag, and those that exist only in `CompleteResults` should be ignored. Something like:

```
Name        ID  SecondName  SecondID
example     1   Not found   Not found
example     2   xxx         22
example     3   xxx         33
example     4   xxx         44
example     5   xxx         55
example2    1   yyy         111
example2    2   yyy         222
example2    3   yyy         333
example2    4   yyy         444
example2    5   yyy         555
```

Comment: What have you tried? You could use an Index/Match formula to get this.  I answered a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784228/vlookup-alternative-using-three-lookup-values) earlier.  Check there and see if you can understand how to use Index/Match for your cells.

Comment: I have tried to concatenate Name-ID and SecondName-SecondID to VLOOKUP, but im not being able to do this... getting N/A all the time

Comment: Did you look at the Index/Match option in the link I posted? (the link is the "a similar question" text in my previous comment).