# How can I use VLOOKUP to search for multiple entries in one cell and to output the result similarly?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have an Excel cell with the data "1, 2, 3".

I want to use VLOOKUP to search for these numbers in another table and to return multiple values associated with them.

From what I looked up I need to make a new function, but none of them seemed to work for me.

The formula I have used so far is

```
Function LookupConcat(r As String, lookupColumn As Range, lngOffset As Long) As String
Dim t, u As Long, c As Range, s As String
t = Split(r, ",")
For u = 0 To UBound(t)
    Set c = lookupColumn.Find(Trim(t(u)))
    If Not c Is Nothing Then s = s & c.Offset(, lngOffset - 1) & ", "
Next
If Len(s) Then LookupConcat = Left(s, Len(s) - 2)
End Function
```

The table I want to use this on is

B    C
ID    ID2
1     10
1     5
2     20
3     25

I am also using =lookupconcat(A2,B2:C4,2) to return the value

A2 has the values "1,2,3"

And I want the function to return "10, 5, 20, 25"

But All I got was 0

Comment: Please post what formula you have, a sample table, a sample of the expected output.  Also, you may instead want to look into [Index/Match](http://thinketg.com/say-goodbye-to-vlookup-and-hello-to-index-match/), which can use multiple values to look something up.  I answered a question similar to this a little bit ago: [this may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784228/vlookup-alternative-using-three-lookup-values/33784647#33784647).  Otherwise, please clarify your question a little more and show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: @BruceWayne Hi, I have updated my question

Comment: @BruceWayne I'm a huge fan of INDEX/MATCH but VLOOKUP can do the same multiple-value lookup. Interesting I/M article you linked. To really understand INDEX, I'd humbly recommend this article:  http://www.excelhero.com/blog/2011/03/the-imposing-index.html

Comment: Wow! The update COMPLETELY changes the question! Can you also include how you are calling the `LookupConcat` function?

Comment: What does this User Defined Function have to do with VLOOKUP?

Comment: @ExcelHero Hi, I updated the question. I am really not familiar with coding on excel so I just googled "vlookup comma separated values" and it was in one of the articles there. (http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/757890-function-lookup-comma-separated-list-within-single-cell-return-concatenated-results-single-cell.html)